# save adview in cache for faster loading

Tags: android, caching, ads

I've got two different activities in my application. One contains a surfaceview with an actual game and the other is the "game over screen" containing an adview and a "new game" button. 
Now my problem is, when the gameover screen gets called, the adview takes some time to load. So when the user is fast enough he's able to press the new game button without even having seen the ad, because it was still loading. 
Is it possible to load this ad, save it in some cache and immediately bring it back to front when the game over activity gets called the next time?

The adview is built programmatically (not via xml files). This is my code for it:

```
public class GameOverScreen extends Activity {

    private AdView adView();
    private RelativeLayout rLayout;

    protected void onCreate() {
        adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setUnitId(xxx);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        AdRequest.Builder adBuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();
        adBuilder.addTestDevice(xxx);
        rLayout.addView(adView);
        adView.loadAd(adbuilder.build());
    }
}
```